# String matching inside JSON format

Tags: java, regex, json

I am using a simple regexp matcher to match a piece of JSON text in wikidump. The JSON is inside XML. I have retrieved the contents of XML tag `<text>` in a string `str`.
The code is

```
str.matches(".*&quot;m&quot;:[&quot;value&quot;,569,&quot;time&quot;,\\{&quot;time&quot;:&quot;+00000001952-03-11.*")
```

(I am giving the exact format inside the tag `<text>` here)

There is a problem with the `{`, so I included `\\{`, still not working. I am not really bothered about the `{` there, but I don't know how else to escape it.

The error is:

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near
>   index 94
>   .*"m":["value",569,"time",{"time":"+00000001952-03-11.*
>   ^     at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1924)     at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.range(Pattern.java:2594)  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2507)  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2030)   at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1964)   at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1665)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.(Pattern.java:1337)     at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1022)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Pattern.java:1128)    at
>   java.lang.String.matches(String.java:2063)    at
>   testProjectone.birthDate.testbirthDate(birthDate.java:64)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Comment: Can you give a sample string that you are trying to match?

Comment: the only string I am trying to match is : & quot;m& quot;:[& quot;value& quot;,569,& quot;time& quot;,\\{& quot;time& quot;:& quot;+00000001952-03-11  and it is without thw space between & and quot . the string actually has the "quot" word in it. But it is getting displayed as " when i given it along wid &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape `[`, since it will be interpreted by the engine as the start of a character class `[]`.

Another thing you need to escape is `+` in `+0000000`, since `+` is interpreted as repeating previous character (which is `;`) once or more.

```
".*&quot;m&quot;:\\[&quot;value&quot;,569,&quot;time&quot;,\\{&quot;time&quot;:&quot;\\+00000001952-03-11.*"
```

A simple way of construct a regex when you have a long fixed string you want to find is to use [`Pattern.quote(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
".*" + Pattern.quote("&quot;m&quot;:[&quot;value&quot;,569,&quot;time&quot;,{&quot;time&quot;:&quot;+00000001952-03-11") + ".*"
```

The part of text in between `.*` will all be treated as literal characters.

Answer (score 0):

Method call you mentioned

`str.matches("."m":["value",569,"time",\{"time":"+00000001952-03-11."`

is a problem. Double quotes within double quotes in the method argument is a problem.

Comment: the string actually has the "quot" word in it. But it is getting displayed as " when i given it along wid & . It is like & quot;m& quot;:[& quot;value& quot;,569,& quot;time& quot;,\\{& quot;time& quot;:& quot;+00000001952-03-11